# VB.NET SocketException receiving data, after 1h of works

Tags: vb.net, sockets, exception, vb.net-2010

I have an Exception that I don't understand. After 1h of correct works I receive this exception. My code sends TCP strings to a server and receive strings back.

[image]

This piece of code works well for a lot but after a periode it crash.
Do you know a way to better manage the exception or don't stops the running?

Comment: The server disconnected, that happens.  You are trying to catch the wrong exception type, catch SocketException instead.

Comment: thanks. I will try. I also find that one address change to null and this can be a possible cause...